# Kill pid by found name in adb shell

Tags: android, windows, shell, adb, ps

I am trying kill the process by pid but without success yet.
To get pid I use command in adb shell:

```
echo $(ps |grep myword) | cut -d' ' -f2
```

To kill pid I use command:

```
kill <PID>
```

But I cannot join that two commands.. What I've tried was:

```
kill $($(ps |grep debug) | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

but it is somehow wrong. Could I ask you for a help?

**tl;dr**

The problem is about joining two commands in adb shell, android console -to kill process found by name.

```
echo $(ps |grep myword) | cut -d' ' -f2
kill <PID>
```

---

**I forgot to say**: I am working on Windows7, so grep might not working in console. **Really sorry for this.**

I also tried this command:

```
adb shell "su -c 'echo $(ps | grep process_name) | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill'"
```

This example is working well, however last part `xargs` fails:

```
adb shell ^" "su -c 'echo $(ps | grep ror)'|cut -d' ' -f2"
```

Comment: Try this : `ps | grep debug | awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill`

Comment: if you have busybox installed use `busybox killall app_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for command adb shell in windows7 was:

```
adb shell ^" "su -c 'ps | echo $(grep process_name) | cut -d " " -f2 |xargs kill '"
```

Comment: there is a problem with `cut -d " " -f2` part - it would return PID only when there was exactly 1 space between UID and PID, which is not always the case.

Comment: you are right, it is possible to use regexp

Answer (score 4):

The process can be killed the following ways (On Linux System).

1. With *your* approach, the command (on ADB shell) should be as follows:
   `echo $(ps | grep process_name) | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill`
2. On ADB shell
   `ps | grep process_name | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`
   On the host machine as
   `adb shell ps | grep process_name | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill`
3. You can use [`busybox`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-busybox/) and do it.
   You can also build your own command (ex. `pkill`), like shown [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-busybox/#N1023F). `killall` is already supported by `busybox`.

Option `one` should resolve your query, I would prefer the `second` option.

Comment: numer 1 is cool however I need su, I don't want use busybox. What I need is to start command with `adb shell...` Numer 2 is okay but I am working on Win7

Comment: Looks like to me, to kill any process you would require `su` or `sudo`
Which device are you working on ?

I believe `busybox` would also require root!

Comment: Yes but I really don't want to use bb, okay `su` might be required

Comment: Again, Which device are you working on ?

Comment: android, nexus 4, api > 4.4.4, I am calling commands from window's console

Answer (score 0):

Kill with single adb command:

```
adb shell "for pid in  \`ps  | grep process_name | sed 's/  */ /g' | \
     cut -d ' '  -f 2 \`; do kill \$pid; done"
```